# How to plot timeseries with uneven timescale

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

In my data below, events happen over different time spans. The first 8 lines, for instance, within 100 microseconds of each other. While the following happen within a few seconds.

I am trying to plot the changes of `bid_size_1` over time. The issue with this scale of time series is that the changes at the microsecond levels are invisible in comparison to the changes at the second level. All the information of the first 8 lines is condensed in the area circled in red (again, due to the extremely short timescale):

[image: Graph]

```
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
|        event_timestamp        | bid_size_1 | ask_size_1 |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253234659 |    110.0   |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253258248 |    30.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253284376 |    65.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253286780 |    96.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253293758 |    146.0   |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253299003 |    146.0   |    125.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253334034 |    161.0   |    125.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.259143344 |    111.0   |    125.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:33.831668204 |    76.0    |    125.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:34.300859840 |    61.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:35.250246888 |    70.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:42.867285196 |    40.0    |    145.0   |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

I tried using log scale, but it didn't help.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data
data = {
    'event_timestamp': [
        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253234659', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253258248', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253284376',
        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253286780', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253293758', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253299003',
        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253334034', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.259143344', '2023-12-01 09:03:33.831668204',
        '2023-12-01 09:03:34.300859840', '2023-12-01 09:03:35.250246888', '2023-12-01 09:03:42.867285196'
    ],
    'bid_size_1': [
        110.0, 30.0, 65.0, 96.0, 146.0, 146.0, 161.0, 111.0, 76.0, 61.0, 70.0, 40.0
    ],
    'ask_size_1': [
        145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 125.0, 125.0, 125.0, 125.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0
    ]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'event_timestamp' column to datetime
df['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_timestamp'])

# Calculate logarithm of time values
df['log_time'] = np.log(df['event_timestamp'].astype(np.int64))

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(df['log_time'], df['bid_size_1'], marker='o', linestyle='-', label='Bid Size 1')
plt.plot(df['log_time'], df['ask_size_1'], marker='o', linestyle='-', label='Ask Size 1')
plt.title('Bid Size 1 and Ask Size 1 Over Time (Logarithmic)')
plt.xlabel('Log(Time)')
plt.ylabel('Size')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**
BAR CHART BUTTERFLY CHART INSTEAD OF LINES

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data
data = {
    'event_timestamp': [
        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253234659', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253258248', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253284376',
        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253286780', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253293758', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253299003',
        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253334034', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.259143344', '2023-12-01 09:03:33.831668204',
        '2023-12-01 09:03:34.300859840', '2023-12-01 09:03:35.250246888', '2023-12-01 09:03:42.867285196'
    ],
    'bid_size_1': [
        110.0, 30.0, 65.0, 96.0, 146.0, 146.0, 161.0, 111.0, 76.0, 61.0, 70.0, 40.0
    ],
    'ask_size_1': [
        145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 125.0, 125.0, 125.0, 125.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0
    ]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = quotes_grouped       #pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'event_timestamp' column to datetime
df['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_timestamp'])
df["time_ns_shifted"] = (df["event_timestamp"] - df["event_timestamp"].min()).astype(np.int64)

# Plotting
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

# PRIMARY AXIS
# Plot bid_price_1 (blue dashed line)
ax1.bar(df['time_ns_shifted'], df['bid_size_1'], color='blue', alpha=0.5, label='Bid Size')
# Plot ask_price_1 (red dashed line)
ax1.bar(df['time_ns_shifted'], -df['ask_size_1'], color='red', alpha=0.5, label='Ask Size')
# Axis label
ax1.set_xlabel('Log of time_ns_shifted')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price', color='black')

plt.title('Bid Size 1 and Ask Size 1 Over Time (Logarithmic)')
plt.xlabel('Log(Time)')
plt.ylabel('Size')

plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xscale("log")
plt.show()
```

Comment: How do you want it to be plotted?  If you don't care about time, then just plot it versus sample number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider plotting it versus the shifted time.

```py
df["time_ns_shifted"] = (df["event_timestamp"] - df["event_timestamp"].min()).astype(np.int64)
```

And use the built-in log scaling.

```py
plt.plot(df["time_ns_shifted"], df['bid_size_1'], marker='o', linestyle='-', label='Bid Size 1')
plt.plot(df["time_ns_shifted"], df['ask_size_1'], marker='o', linestyle='-', label='Ask Size 1')
plt.xscale("log")
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as it does the opposite. For timeframe far into the future, that gets crunched into a very short window because the log function  reduces those large numbers to be much closer